# How to view htm file that with vbscript without IE?

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer, html

It's audit time here again, and as per usual, I remote into servers, and run gpresult /h to generate a human-readable RSoP to include in my audit evidence.

Unfortunately, the security guy says that I have to remove IE from my machine, and it's the only browser that will run the VBScript in the file that gpresult produces.

What to do?

The result is still kinda readable, but I can't collapse the sections in the htm file to make it easier for the auditor to find what he needs.

Is there a browser, extension, or setting out there I can turn on to make these run the script?
Or is there an alternative to gpresult?

Comment: What does IE have to do with running a script? We aren't mind readers. We also don't know what is in the so called "script" you are running.

Comment: @GregAskew I think he talk about the gpresult .htm's file which is formated for IE.

Comment: @yagmoth555: I think he has a VBScript that is using an IE component - it doesn't work when IE is removed. The gpresult html files look fine in Edge or most other browsers, including indentation. The answer is time to move on from VBScript to PowerShell or something else. Designing code requiring a component from a browser that no longer exists probably wasn't the best strategy.

Comment: When you run a resultant set of policy in windows by running gpresult /h from the command line, Windows generates a HTML file with VBScript in it.  It's not something that I make, it's a Microsoft Windows thing.